# WebRTC - Video conferencing with only one emitter

Tags: webrtc, chat

I am new to WebRTC technology.
I want to create a video chat / video conferencing with a transmitter and many followers (more 1000).

Example:

[image]

I read a lot of documentations :

- https://medium.com/linagora-engineering/scalability-in-video-conferencing-part-1-276f52b4acac
- https://webrtcglossary.com/sfu/

But I still don't know what is the best solution (in my case) between Selective Forwarding Unit (SFU) and Multiploint Control Unit (MCU).

Can you help me to understand?
I think the best way is MCU but I am not sure.

Second question:

Can you suggest some sources and links that can help me to set up such an architecture. Currently my project works perfectly in Peer To Peer (Mesh) but it is not the right solution. I have absolutely no idea how to set this up.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement this using an SFU. The more peers are connected, the more you would need processing power to handle those new peers. This could be done by using more threads and/or forwarding requests to another machine.

With [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/) it is possible have control over this. With this tool you have routers where peers can connect to to get the stream. A router works on a worker which has a limited amount of receiving peers (depending on cpu capacity). Now to allow more peers you can forward the stream to other routers which can expand the total capacity.

useful links:

- https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/scalability/#one-to-many-broadcasting
- https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/mediasoup/design/#architecture
- https://mediasoup.discourse.group/t/scalability-in-mediasoup-example/793/2?u=dirvann